# Can't copy existing property

Tags: python, scripting, properties

Why this lattice property from "properties panel" can't be copied?
[image]
however i can copy another property e.g object location to "My Panel"

here the simple script what i've done

```
import bpy


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "MY_PT_Panel"
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_category = "Tool"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        
        lat = context.lattice
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(lat, "points_u", text="Resolution U")
        
        obj = context.object
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(obj, "location")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

please help does i'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`context.lattice` only exists in PROPERTIES area**

There are different context members available in different spaces in blender. Always look for this in code copied from the  properties space. In this case [`context.lattice`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html?highlight=properties%20context#buttons-context) for the data part of a lattice object, similarly `context.speaker`

A rule of thumb test to check a context member  via py console.

```
>>> C.lattice
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'lattice'
```

Can set a context pointer in the UI, have added to code below and commented out.  Look for this in the properties space UI python file.

Or simply set it from the data of a lattice type context object

```
lat = context.object.data
```

The poll method ensures the context object is only of type lattice for the panel to poll and hence be drawn.

```
import bpy


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "MY_PT_Panel"
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_category = "Tool"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"


    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        ob = context.object
        return ob and ob.type == 'LATTICE'
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        # set a context pointer
        #layout.context_pointer_set("lattice", context.object.data)
        #lat = context.lattice
        # or use the object data
        lat = context.object.data
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(lat, "points_u", text="Resolution U")
        
        obj = context.object
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(obj, "location")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```